# super.onBackPressed() ou finish()?

Tags: android

Qual a diferença entre os métodos? no caso do super.onBackPressed() só se pode usar dentro do método onBackPressed() certo?

Comment: Qual o contexto e o que exatamente você quer fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando chamas `super.onBackPressed()` **sempre** dentro do `onBackPressed()` quer dizer que estás a assumir o comportamento por defeito do botão `back` do dispositivo, ou seja, "recuar" que termina a atividade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[Fonte da Imagem](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)</sup>

A ideia de fazer *override* da função `onBackPressed()` é tu poderes definir o comportamento que quiseres quando o utilizador clica no botão `back` do dispositivo. Se chamares o `super.onBackPressed()` estás a manter o comportamento do botão `back`, mesmo assim podes adicionar outros comportamentos como guardar variáveis antes de fechar a atividade.

O `finish()` (também) serve para terminar a atividade que está a correr, a qualquer altura, sem ser necessário usar o botão `back`. Podes até usar outro botão da tua app para terminar a actividade.